# Meaning of "(OF)" or "(OF+)" in linux kernel crash report

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to know the meaning of these symbols i.e "**(OF)**" or "**(OF)+**" specified along with module name in Linux kernel trace. Can some one help to understand this as i am unable to find anything about this online.

Here is the trace i got.

```
general protection fault: 0000 [#1]
Modules linked in: cxgb4(OF+) toecore(OF) ip6table_filter ip6_tables
ebtable_nat ebtables nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_state nf_conntrack
.....
....
CPU: 5 PID: 15240 Comm: modprobe Tainted: GF          O 3.11.10 #1
Hardware name: Supermicro X9DRD-iF/LF/X9DRD-iF, BIOS 3.0b 12/05/2013
task: ffff88046c1660c0 ti: ffff88045f4da000 task.ti: ffff88045f4da000
RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff812674aa>]  [<ffffffff812674aa>]
kobject_uevent_env+0x5a/0x5e0
...
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'P' - Proprietary module has been loaded.
'F' - Module has been forcibly loaded.
'S' - SMP with CPUs not designed for SMP.
'R' - User forced a module unload.
'M' - System experienced a machine check exception.
'B' - System has hit bad_page.
'U' - Userspace-defined naughtiness.
'D' - Kernel has oopsed before
'A' - ACPI table overridden.
'W' - Taint on warning.
'C' - modules from drivers/staging are loaded.
'I' - Working around severe firmware bug.
'O' - Out-of-tree module has been loaded.

'+' -  Module is being loaded, probably running module_init
'-' -  Module is being unloaded (state is set only after module_exit returns)
```

**Sources:**

[Documentation/oops-tracing.txt](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.14.1/Documentation/oops-tracing.txt#L230)
[kernel/module.c](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.14.1/kernel/module.c#L3590)
[include/linux/module.h](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.14.1/include/linux/module.h#L211)
[kernel/panic.c](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.14.1/kernel/panic.c#L218)

Comment: Nice ans, can you post a reference link as well ?

Comment: @brokenfoot I got it from the kernel source. http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.14.1/Documentation/oops-tracing.txt#L230  http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.14.1/kernel/module.c#L3590 http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.14.1/include/linux/module.h#L211 http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.14.1/kernel/panic.c#L218